# Parsing an XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml , and I want to parse it. I have transformed it into a string, but I don't know how to iterate through the Cube's children to get the data I'm interested in (the currency rates). Any help, please? Thanks.

Comment: I have tried kind of every answer present here. What I can't do, it's to navigate to the "Cube" element and read all its children and put them into something (a dictionary, a list or something). All I can get is a big string of the xml. Please help. I want to iterate through it somehow and get its data.

Comment: You mean none of the answers has helped you?

Comment: Yeah, either that or I didn't succeed to implement them the way I wanted. There is an article on one of the answers below, but they are showing how to loop through an xml file that begins with the tag they are interested in. Either I don't understand how to do it, or I'm too stupid. I need a little bit of help, that's for sure.

Comment: For me, @LB's answer answers your question. What's wrong with it? We can't guess if you don't post the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

And by the help of [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp), all nodes become easily accessible.

Code sample:

```
WebRequest webRequestSearch = WebRequest.Create("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
WebResponse webResponseSearch = webRequestSearch.GetResponse();
Stream streamSearch = webResponseSearch.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader oReaderSearch = new StreamReader(streamSearch, Encoding.GetEncoding(1254));
strTempHtml = oReaderSearch.ReadToEnd();     
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(strTempHtml);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//cube/rate");
string currency1 = nodes[0].Attributes["currency"].Value;
string currency1Value =nodes[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: Why are you using the HtmlAgilityPack to parse XML?

Comment: I know it is not the best way to parse xml but still easy. just want to show another way.

Comment: I'm just curious. What have you found in the agility pack for XML that's not out of the box in the bace class library?

Comment: I have not found anything in the agility pack for XML that's not out of the box in the base class library :) if you found, it will be appreciated to hear from you.

Comment: That's my question. Why are you using it then?

Comment: If I need to do simple operations on xml, agility pack seems easier to me. But I think the question should be that which way is faster? I will check this and come again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML, there is many examples and explanations on this website:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

Answer (score 0):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.bnr.ro/xsd";
var rates = XDocument.Load("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml")
            .Descendants(ns + "Rate")
            .Select(r => new
            {
                Currency = r.Attribute("currency").Value,
                Value = (decimal)r,
                Multiplier = (int?)r.Attribute("multiplier")
            })
            .ToList();
```